# Trying to make the clock function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, project, codepen

And thanks for stopping by.

I've been trying to add a feature, or function, to a project that I'm working on, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

When my project loads I want the user to activate the time as soon as they move, or click, one of the orbs -- not as soon as the project loads. I know there's an onClick or click event, but I'm having trouble implementing it on the js code. I've gone as far as commenting-out or "greying" entire functions to test things out.

Here's some of the time code:

```
function clockStart() {
    numberOfSecs = setInterval(function () {
        seconds.text(`${second}`)
        second = second + 1
    }, 1000);
}

function rewindSec(seconds) {
    if (seconds) {
        clearInterval(seconds);
    }
}

gameStart();

// GAMES BEGIN!!!
function gameStart() {
    var cards = shuffle(listOfCards);
    deckOfCards.empty();
    match = 0;
    Moves = 0;
    moveNum.text("0");
    ratingStars.removeClass("fa-angry").addClass("fa-star");
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        deckOfCards.append($('<li class="card"><i class="fab fa-' + cards[i] + '"></i></li>'))
    }
    sourceCard();

    rewindSec(numberOfSecs);
    second = 0;
    seconds.text(`${second}`)
    clockStart();
};
```

Here's a link to the project that I'm talking about:

Full Page View: https://codepen.io/idSolomon/full/RYPZNp/

Editor View: https://codepen.io/idSolomon/pen/RYPZNp/?editors=0010

WARNING: Project not mobile-friendly. At least not yet.

If someone can help me out with this, a thousand thank yous will come your way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can **Change the event of starting the clock at another position**

First remove the **clockStart()** function from the **gameStart()** method

```
seconds.text(`${second}`)
//clockStart();
```

if have added an Extra variable to detect if the clock is started or not

```
var isClockStarted=false;
```

The following code will start the timer when a card is clicked:

```
var sourceCard = function () {

deckOfCards.find(".card").bind("click", function () {
if(!isClockStarted)
clockStart();
```

The Bellow Code will check if the timer is started or not.

```
function clockStart() {
if(!isClockStarted){
    isClockStarted=true;
numberOfSecs = setInterval(function () {
    seconds.text(`${second}`)
    second = second + 1
}, 1000);
```

}
}

I have found that you are not stopping the timer even after the game finishes

If canceled a game it starts timer again //toCheck

Comment: Hi Hitech! Thanks a lot for looking into this. I've done something like that, but I guess I must've missed a semi-colon or something. When I refresh the page and click on a card the timer works. Unfortunately when I reboot the project via the restart button, the timer doesn't budge.